# ScrollViewer doesn't scroll for custom panel

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I am making my own custom panel, which is supposed to scroll vertically when the content does not fit the available space, so i put it in a ScrollViewer.
Right now i can't get the ScrollViewer to activate the scrollbar when the panel inside is bigger then the ScrollViewer itself.

The permille functions get attached properties telling how big the childs have to be compared to the available size (without scrolling), aka the ViewPort.
As the size passed in MeasureOverride passes infinite, i don't think i can use the permille functions there.
That is why i measure my children in ArrangeOverride (not best practice, i guess) but that way the scrollviewer doesn't scroll.

How do i get this to work?

**My XAML code:**

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <controls:TilePanel x:Name="TilePanel" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TilePanel_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="TilePanel_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" 
                        PreviewMouseMove="TilePanel_PreviewMouseMove" DragEnter="TilePanel_DragEnter" Drop="TilePanel_Drop" AllowDrop="True" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

**My Custom Panel Class:**

```
/// <summary>
/// A Panel Showing Tiles
/// </summary>
public class TilePanel : PermillePanel
{
        public TilePanel()
        {
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            //here constraint width or height can be infinite.
            //as tiles are a permille of that height, they too can be infinite after measuring
            //this is unwanted behavior, so we measure in the ArrangeOverride method

            if (constraint.Width == double.PositiveInfinity)
            {
                return new Size(0, constraint.Height);
            }
            else if (constraint.Height == double.PositiveInfinity)
            {
                return new Size(constraint.Width, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                return constraint;
            }
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
        {
            //return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);

            foreach (FrameworkElement child in InternalChildren)
            {
                Size availableSize = new Size();
                //set the width and height for the child
                availableSize.Width = arrangeSize.Width * TilePanel.GetHorizontalPermille(child) / 1000;
                availableSize.Height = arrangeSize.Height * TilePanel.GetVerticalPermille(child) / 1000;

                child.Measure(availableSize);

            }

            // arrange the children on the panel
            // fill lines horizontally, when we reach the end of the current line, continue to the next line

            Size newSize = new Size(arrangeSize.Width, arrangeSize.Height);

            double xlocation = 0;
            double ylocation = 0;

            double ystep = 0;

            double maxYvalue = 0;

            foreach (FrameworkElement child in InternalChildren)
            {
                double endxlocation = xlocation + child.DesiredSize.Width;

                double constrainedWidth = arrangeSize.Width * TilePanel.GetHorizontalPermille(child) / 1000;
                double constrainedHeight = arrangeSize.Height * TilePanel.GetVerticalPermille(child) / 1000;

                if (TilePanel.GetVerticalPermille(child) != 0 && TilePanel.GetHorizontalPermille(child) != 0)
                {
                    //horizontal overflow -> next line
                    if (endxlocation >= this.DesiredSize.Width *1.01)
                    {
                        ylocation += ystep;
                        xlocation = 0;
                    }
                }

                Rect rect = new Rect(xlocation, ylocation, constrainedWidth, constrainedHeight);
                child.Arrange(rect);
                xlocation += constrainedWidth;
                ystep = Math.Max(ystep, constrainedHeight);
                maxYvalue = Math.Max(maxYvalue, ystep + constrainedHeight);
            }

            if (maxYvalue > newSize.Height)
            {
                newSize.Height = maxYvalue;
            }

            return newSize;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Measure()` from within `ArrangeOverride()` will cause problems.  The framework detects this and forces a remeasure.  Set a tracepoint in `MeasureOverride()`, and I'll bet you'll see that it keeps getting called over and over again, even though the layout hasn't changed<sup>1</sup>.

If you absolutely have to call `Measure()` from `ArrangeOverride()`, you will need to do so conditionally such that it only forces a remeasure when the available size actually changes since the last call to `Measure()`.  Then, you'll effectively end up with two measure + arrange passes any time the layout is invalidated, as opposed to just one.  However, such an approach is hacky, and I would advise sticking to the best practice of only measuring within `MeasureOverride()`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Interestingly, your UI may still respond to input, despite this apparent "infinite loop" in the layout.

Comment: in fact, asking my controls to Measue in the ArrayngeOverride function does not call an endless loop (verified by breakpoints in code). The conditional method had no avail. I agree on calling Measure in MeasureOverride, but i don't see how i can as i scale my children based on the viewport.

Comment: Even if it doesn't throw you into a layout loop, it can still cause odd behavior, particularly for controls nested within a `ScrollViewer`.  You could move the measure code back to `MeasureOverride` if you constrain the available space to some large but non-infinite value, or the viewport size of an ancestor `ScrollViewer`.  Alternatively, you could compute the "ideal size" in `ArrangeOverride`, store it in a field, and invalidate the measure to force a second layout pass (and then return the ideal width/height from `MeasureOverride()` instead of zero).  Be careful to avoid loops, though.

Comment: tried it with the loops, got pretty close but still had some weird behavior. I Ended up working with a Canvas and placing my controls by setting the height, width, left and top. Not as pretty and probably not as fast but it does the job, i guess

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a custom `Panel` inside a `ScrollViewer` then you must add the code that does the actual scrolling. You can do that by implementing the [`IScrollInfo` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) in your custom `Panel`.

You can find a tutorial that explains this interface and provides an example code imeplementation in the [WPF Tutorial - Implementing IScrollInfo](http://tech.pro/tutorial/907/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo) page on the Tech Pro website. It's a fairly simple procedure and looks a tiny bit like this:

```
public void LineDown() { SetVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset + LineSize); }

public void LineUp() { SetVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset - LineSize); }

public void MouseWheelDown() { SetVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset + WheelSize); }

public void MouseWheelUp() { SetVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset - WheelSize); }

public void PageDown() { SetVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset + ViewportHeight); }

public void PageUp() { SetVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset - ViewportHeight); }

...
```

Comment: Implementing `IScrollInfo` should only be necessary if the OP wants to support custom scrolling behavior when `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"`.  Simple pixel-level scrolling should just work.

Comment: This is not what i was looking for, but perhaps i can use it as a last resort.

Comment: You only need to use `IScrollInfo` if you want to scroll by custom amounts, as opposed to using the default scroll behavior.  For example, you might want `LineDown()` (clicking the 'down' scroll button) to scroll exactly one row of tiles into view.  It isn't an ideal solution to your current problem, but it's useful stuff to know.